# Alternative to breadcrumbs in navigating groups of content

Tags: breadcrumbs

I'm looking for other ways on how to help User easily navigate groups. Instead of going back to 'All Groups' via breadcrumbs, User may want to go directly to Group 9 while he/she is on Group 1 Details Page.

[image: alternative to breadcrumbs]

Solution 1: I thought of adding a dropdown to just easily navigate to the rest of the groups. 
Solution 2: Add a thumbnail below so the User would see exactly where he/she want to go next.

[image]

My ultimate goal is remove completely breadcrumb and would be happy to hear your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider providing "Related Links" on the details pages, which go to sibling links or, as I think you're describing, to aunt and uncle links. You wouldn't want to provide links to every other category; you'd want to select the most relevant ones.

I'm wondering, though, how often do people navigate between the categories? Does each user typically focus on products from a single category? A close look at your analytics (or doing some usability tests) can help understand your users' behaviors.

Comment: The categories could be on Normal, Warning or Danger status. The user's top priority is to check the categories that are in Warning status. "Related Links' is a good approach. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered putting the group-switching dropdown inside the breadcrumb?

[image]

Comment: I haven't considered dropdown on breadcrumb so this is really a good solution on how to easily navigate in between groups. Thanks!